# Laravel Sanctum returns randomly 401 after succesfully authenticating

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, http-status-code-401, laravel-sanctum

I am developing a dashboard using Laravel and VueJS, with both on different servers. I have no problems with my local development environment on my PC and the production server. However, on the staging server, Laravel randomly returns a 401 error.

Here is my environment settings on the staging server, for this question I replaced the real domain with 'example.com':

```
    ENV (staging)
    APP_ENV=staging
    APP_DEBUG=false
    SESSION_DRIVER=database
    SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=https://api.staging.example.com,https://staging.example.com,localhost,https://example.com
    SESSION_DOMAIN=.example.com
```

The login process always returns a 200 with a token included in each request (ofcourse when the creditials are correct). Vue then makes five requests to the server, (which include the bearer token retrieved through the login request) all of which are defined in the same `Route::apiResources([]);` block inside of a `Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:sanctum'], function () {...}`.

Most of the time, three requests return a 401 error and two requests return a 200 with JSON. To make matters worse, it's not always the same requests that result in the 401 error.

For instance, sometimes requests 1, 3, and 5 return a 401 and the other two return a 200. After a reload or new login with the same user, requests 1, 2, and 4 return a 401 and 3 and 5 return a 200.

I have tried the following commands at least one million times, but they do not solve the issue:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
php artisan config:cache
```